# How to get row id of particular row from legacy jQuery data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I had gone through

http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/

It shows a nice way to retrieve row id

```
// Handle click on checkbox
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e){
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');

    // Get row data
    var data = table.row($row).data();

    // Get row ID
    var rowId = data[0];
```

However, I need to stick with legacy DataTable 1.9.4. I try to perform the similar thing.

```
$('#confirm-table').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var data = table.fnGetData($row[0]);
    var rowId = data[0];

    // I expect to get "123" or "456". But I am getting '<input type="checkbox">'
    alert(rowId);
})
```

As you can see, what I did is I convert current DataTable code from

```
var data = table.row($row).data();
```

to legacy DataTable code

```
var data = table.fnGetData($row[0]);
```

However, instead of getting row id ("123" or "456"), I'm getting rendered code `<input type="checkbox">`

Any idea how to do it in proper way?

---

https://jsfiddle.net/14p9uu8c/

Here's the fully workable code to demonstrate the problem

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.9.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="confirm-table">
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
    var dataSet = [
        [ "123", "System Architect" ],
        [ "456", "Accountant" ]
    ];

    table = $('#confirm-table').dataTable( {
        aaData: dataSet,
        aoColumns: [
            { sTitle: "Id" },
            { sTitle: "Job" }
        ],
        "aoColumnDefs":[ {
            "aTargets": [0],
            "fnRender": function ( oObj ) {
                return '<input type="checkbox">';
            }
        }]
    } );

    $('#confirm-table').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
        var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var data = table.fnGetData($row[0]);
        var rowId = data[0];

        // I expect to get "123" or "456". But I am getting '<input type="checkbox">'
        alert(rowId);
    });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle of your code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/14p9uu8c/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all we need to convert your existing `aaData` to json objects. Then we have our `aoColumns` to match our `aaData`. After it's done lets update `aoColumnDefs`.

Instead of rendering our `DT_RowId` column content as a checkbox, lets hide our that column so we can easily access the `DT_RowId` data.

I did not change your `onClick` listener.

Here is working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
    var dataSet = [
        {
            "DT_RowId": "123",
            "checkbox": "",
            "job": "System Architect"
        },
        {
            "DT_RowId": "456",
            "checkbox": "",
            "job": "Accountant"
        }
    ];

    table = $('#confirm-table').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        aaData: dataSet,
        aoColumns: [
            { "mData": "DT_RowId" , sTitle: "Hidden row Id"  },
            { "mData": "checkbox" , sTitle: "Id"  },
            { "mData": "job", sTitle: "Job" } // <-- which values to use inside object
             
        ],
        "aoColumnDefs":[ 
            {
                "aTargets": [0],
                "bVisible": false
            },
            {
                "aTargets": [1],
                "fnRender": function ( oObj, value ) {
                    return '<input type="checkbox">';
                }
            }
        ]
    } );

    $('#confirm-table').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
        var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var data = table.fnGetData($row[0]);
        var rowId = data[0];


        // I expect to get "123" or "456". But I am getting '<input type="checkbox">'
        console.log(data.DT_RowId);
    });

});
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.9.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>



<table id="confirm-table">
</table>
```